# Vim:Fugitive:Glog - How to get commits for current file rather than revisions

Tags: git, vim, vim-fugitive

Currently, if I type `:Glog` I get the list of *revisions* for the *current file*.

If I type `:Glog --` I get the list of *commits* for *all files*.

What do I need to type to get the of *commits* for the *current file*?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I figured it out. I found it [here.](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/issues/363)

```
:Glog -- %
```

Comment: How is this the accepted answer when the link referred cites tpope explicitly stating: "Fugitive provides the -- % for you, and if you give a -- yourself, it assumes you want something other than the current file, drops that behavior, and opens the commit instead."

Answer (score 39):

For sake of completeness, once you have the revisions loaded in your buffer, you can browse through them by opening the quickfix list

```
:Glog -- %
:copen
```

Load the last 10 commits for the current file

```
:Glog -10 -- %
```

Comment: And appending a ! will prevent the first match to open.

:Glog! -- %

Will just fill the quickfixt list without opening the first.

Answer (score 13):

I use

```
:0Gclog
```

It puts the commits history of current file into quick fix so that you can use `]q` or `[q` to go through them

Note that the usage supports range: `:{range}Gclog`. So you can use any range, e.g. `:1Gclog` or use a visual mapping:

```
vmap <leader>gl :Gclog<CR>
```

Comment: What does the number represent? When I tried it here `:0Gclog` populated the quickfix list with the log history and `:1Gclog`, `:2Gclog` etc populated it with the first commit ever.

Comment: @JoãoPesce The number(s) represents the range in the file to check log for. `0` represents the whole file. Use `:help :Gclog` for the official description.

Answer (score 0):

```
:Git log -- %
```

I also like adding `-p`/`--patch` to see exactly what was changed.